# Restrict the user to put spacebar

Tags: java, joptionpane

I have JOptionPane which asks the user for a String, I wanna be able to restrict the user to input any spacebars, any suggestions?

```
    String firstNumber;

    firstNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ( "Enter file name" );
```

Comment: `" I wanna be able to restrict the user to input any spacebars,..."` -- huh? Please clarify in English. Do you want to prevent spacebar input? If so, then consider using a JDialog that shows a JTextField that uses a DocumentFilter.

Comment: Right now JOptionPane.showInputDialog, shows a text field for user to input text. Without adding a JTextField, can I just restrict it to how it is now? if not, could you post an example code? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean you want to disallow the ability for the user to input spaces?

There are more complex ways, but the easiest would to just remove all spaces from the string after you get it back.

```
firstNumber = firstNumber.replaceAll(" ","");
```

If the length after this is 0, then you can just prompt them again.

Comment: Very nice what I did was;       firstNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ( "Enter file name" ).replaceAll(" ","");